# Clarification of cross-domain AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I'd like to get some clarification on what cross-domain AJAX means in terms of the mechanics behind it.

Say for example, I have a website `http://www.example.com`. This website contains a javascript file, which within contains several standard jQuery based AJAX calls (e.g. `$.post()`, `$.get()` etc), located at `http://www.example.com/js/script.js`.

Now, I have another website `http://www.helloworld.com`, which contains the following;

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/script.js"></script>`

Would the AJAX requests within `http://www.example.com/js/script.js` which make requests to `http://www.example.com` be considered "cross-domain" and therefore carry compatibility issues when the file is included on `http://www.internet.com`?

Any answers would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS is executed on the client side, so it doesn't matter where the source of the file resides, it'll be executed from the domain in the address bar.

Comment: Ah I see. This is a bit OT, and not directly part of the question, but from what I understand, AJAX requests can be made to another domain in the form of say a HTTP GET/POST based request, but any data returned must be in JSONP format?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. You also need to append a callback to your request URL which matches the name of the remote jsonp callback. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to include a javascript from another domain, the sever that serves that JS need to provide the file with the correct headers.
In particular the headers need to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set for the domain requiring a cross-domain JS.

Just for test purpose you might want to run Chrome with the parameter --allow-file-access-from-files and it won't stop cross origin requests.